# General term of the infinite sequence $x_{n}=a+bx_{n+1}$ with $b<1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following sequence:

$$x_{n}=a+bx_{n+1}$$ with $b<1$; $a,b,x_n>0$ and $n=0,1,2,...$.

I want to find the general term of this sequence, so I write
\begin{align}
x_{n}&=a+bx_{n+1}\\
&=a+ab+b^2x_{n+2}\\
&=...\\
&=a(1+b+b^2+....) + b^{\infty}x_{n+\infty}
\end{align}
The first component can be easily calculated as $\frac{a}{1-b}$.
My question is, is it reasonable to write the rest as $b^{\infty}x_{n+\infty}$ and asign it to $0$? If not, is there another approach to this problem?

Comment: This makes sense if $x_n$ converges, otherwise $b^kx_{n+k} $ might not go to $0$ For example take $a=1,b=1/10$ then $x_{n+1}=10x_n-10$. As for general term you get $x_0=a(1+b+\cdots+b^k)+b^kx_k$ from which it shouldn't be hard to find $x_k$ using partial geometric sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{b}x_n-\frac{a}{b}$$
$$\implies (x_{n+1}-\frac{a}{1-b} )= \frac{1}{b}(x_n-\frac{a}{1-b})$$
$$\implies (x_{n+1}-\frac{a}{1-b} )= \frac{1}{b^{n+1}}(x_0-\frac{a}{1-b})$$
or
$$x_n =\frac{1}{b^{n}}(x_0-\frac{a}{1-b})+\frac{a}{1-b}$$